# How to place caption above the "quadro" environment?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

I'm having some trouble with the placement of captions in my LaTeX document. I'm using the trivfloat package to create a "quadro" environment for my tables, similar to the regular "table" environment.

Here's a minimal example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{trivfloat}

\trivfloat{quadro}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Example of a table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 \\
Data 3 & Data 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{quadro}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Example of a quadro}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 \\
Data 3 & Data 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{quadro}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the caption for the "table" environment is placed above the table, which is what I want. However, the caption for the "quadro" environment is placed below the table, and I'd like it to be above the quadro, similar to the "table" environment.

Is there a way to achieve this using the trivfloat package, or is there another package or method I should be using instead?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `trivfloat` uses either `float` (in your case) or `floatrow` for new floats. See the manual of these packages about changing caption position. BTW: An alternative would be to use the `newfloat` package from the same author as `caption`.

Comment: Do you employ the `babel` package? If so, with which language option(s)? Please also clarify if you intend to employ both `table` and `quadro` environments, or just `quadro` environments.

Comment: Thx
I'm using Springer Verlag global LaTeX document class for monographs

Comment: I intend to employ both table and quadro environments.

Comment: FYI crosspost: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=35784

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution by implementing Caboha's advice:
In order to place the caption at the top of my "quadro" environment, I added the floatstyle:
\usepackage{trivfloat} \trivfloat{quadro} \floatstyle{plaintop} \restylefloat{quadro}.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `newfloat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=loq,
  listname=List of Quadros,
  name=Quadro,
  placement=htp,
]{quadro}

\captionsetup[quadro]{position=top}

\begin{document}

\listofquadros

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Example of a table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 \\
Data 3 & Data 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{quadro}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Example of a quadro}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
Data 1 & Data 2 \\
Data 3 & Data 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{quadro}

\end{document}
```

[image]